# How to set bucket properties of a riak cluster using ripple?

Tags: ruby, riak, ripple

I am new to both ripple and riak. Does anyone have an idea, how can I set the bucket properties like

```
n_val
allow_multi
```

etc using ripple in my code. 
I don't want to do it via the curl request:

```
$ curl -v -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"props":{"n_val":5}}'
http://127.0.0.1:8098/riak/test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ripple lets you access the buckets in a way shown:

```
bucket = Ripple.client.bucket("bucket_name")
bucket.allow_mult = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query and update bucket properties using the [Riak Ruby client](https://github.com/basho/riak-ruby-client), which is used by Ripple.